# Does the Bola Shot's Imminent Doom stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

If I shoot a monster multiple times with Bola Shot Imminent Doom (which has a 2 second delay before exploding), do the shots stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this myself. The shots do stack in the sense that shooting a monster twice will result in two explosions on that monster, each after the two second delay has elapsed since each one struck the monster.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about the damage dealt : No the shots don't stack. If you shoot a monster 2 times with the skill, the monster will be hit 2 times.

If your question is about the delay between skill's tick : Yes, shots will stack.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't follow your answer.